# How to destructure an object property from a Pinia getter that returns an object conditionally?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pinia

I got the following Store:

```
export const useMyStore = defineStore('myStore', {
  state: () => {
    return {
      openTransOnly: false,
      keyword: '',
      openTransStatus: { nextPage: 0, complete: false },
      pastDueTransStatus: { nextPage: 0, complete: false },
    };
  },

  getters: {
    transStatus(state) {
      return state.openTransOnly ? state.openTransStatus : state.pastDueTransStatus;
    },
  },
});
```

Now let's say I want to convert the "keyword" property above to a Ref. Here's how I did that:

```
const myStore = useMyStore();
const { keyword: needle } = storeToRefs(myStore);
```

I also have the following computed property in my component:

```
const page = computed({
  get: () => myStore.transStatus.nextPage,
  set: (value) => (myStore.transStatus.nextPage = value),
});
```

which works fine. However, I'd like to know how to use the same "storeToRefs" above to define the "page". I tried this:

```
const { keyword: needle, transStatus: { nextPage: page } } = storeToRefs(myStore);
```

But it says "page is undefined". What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `storeToRefs` name suggests, it returns refs. `transStatus` is a ref and doesn't have `nextPage` property, it is `transStatus.value.nextPage`. Destructuring `nextPage` early would result in the loss of reactivity due to the way `transStatus` works and because the value is scalar.

In case this is a common usage scenario, the store can incorporate `page` computed. Since store state isn't supposed to be mutated outside a store, `page` can be coupled with `setPage` action.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by incorporating the "page"? Do you mean I've to add a new getter named "page" to the Pinia Store? If I do this, what happens to its setter? As far as I know if I go down this path, I won't be able to set the "page".

Comment: Yes. And direct state mutation is against the concept of stores, use an action, setPage.